# Create Angular 1 Browserify module for use in multiple applications

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im trying to create a reusable package of both angular and nodejs code into a single repo, and then use that via bower or npm internally. Taking this simple example below, I cannot get it to work in an existing angular app.

getting the typical angular error below because the module cannot be found.

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module toolkit due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'toolkit' is not available!
```

Here is my test.module.js file.

```
var testService = require('./test.service.js');

angular.module('noble.test', [
]).service('TestService', testService);
```

here is test.service.js

```
module.exports = function($http){
   this.exposedFn = exposedFn;

        ////////////////

        function exposedFn() { 
            alert('Hello!');
        }
}
```

Here is my index.js

```
require('./test/test.module.js')
angular.module('noble.toolkit', [
    'noble.test'
]);
```

directory structure:

```
index.js
   test
       test.service.js
       test.module.js
```

browserify command

```
browserify --entry index.js -o dist.js
```